# TypeScript http get not working?

Tags: c#, typescript

There is simple call I make in TypeScript:

```
getSomeData() {
    return this._http.get(this.somedataUriController).map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

And there is the method in REST API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Data> GetData()
    {
        return new List<Data>
               {
                   new Data
                   {
                       Value = 111,
                   }
               };
    }
```

I can easily call it through browser, but can't do the same thing through {Http}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And why can't you do it through http? What happens when you try?

Comment: Nothing, I mean, no errors, nothing at all.

Comment: Can I take a look at how do you call the `getSomeData` function?

Comment: onSubmit(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        var result = this._dataService.getSomeData();
        alert("Called.");
    }

Comment: How do you know that nothing happened? You don't use the resulting Observable at all. Did you check the developer network panel if the http request is started?

Comment: I looked now and suprisingly request not started O_o

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the first line of `getSomeData`, check if its called. If it is, check the developer console for error messages.